# Boost asio deadline_timer и tcp::socket отослать асинхронно по tcp по таймеру

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, таймер, asio

Цель по tcp соединению отсылать через равные промежутки времени сообщение одно и тоже. Слушать соединение. Цель 2 (не этого вопроса) отсылать случайные сообщения по тому же содержанию, допустимо что бы цель1 не ушла совсем или позже. На основе стандартного примера с сайта boost и где то в интернете найденного таймера накопировал "проект" что бы собирался, но не работает.
Все асинхронно.

Уровень знаний ничтожный.

Обучаюсь на visual studio2017 community но цель переход на Gentoo.

Из структуры timer метод method не видит метод write класса chat_clint создать объект chat_client jj; в структуре timer не получается пишет нет конструктора по умолчанию. Конструктор в классе chat_client пустой - по умолчанию создать не дает библиотека буст.

Тут в коде я помещаю в глобальную очередь (это отличие от примера с сайта) свои байты, это не цель, просто попытка которая собралась, для меня это успех.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include "chat_message.hpp"


using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

boost::asio::io_service io_service;
tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
typedef std::deque<chat_message> chat_message_queue;
chat_message_queue write_msgs_;


 class chat_client
{
 public :   
chat_client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
    : io_service_(io_service),
    socket_(io_service)
{
    boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, endpoint_iterator,
        boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_connect, this,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}
 void write(const chat_message& msg)
{
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&chat_client::do_write, this, msg));
}

void close()
{
    io_service_.post(boost::bind(&chat_client::do_close, this));
}

private:

void handle_connect(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
            boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_header, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}

void handle_read_header(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error && read_msg_.decode_header())
    {
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length()),
            boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_body, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
        do_close();
    }
}

void handle_read_body(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout.write(read_msg_.body(), read_msg_.body_length());
        std::cout << "\n";
        boost::asio::async_read(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(read_msg_.data(), chat_message::header_length),
            boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_read_header, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
        do_close();
    }
}

void do_write(chat_message msg)
{
    bool write_in_progress = !write_msgs_.empty();
    write_msgs_.push_back(msg);
    if (!write_in_progress)
    {
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
                write_msgs_.front().length()),
            boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_write, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
}

void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
    if (!error)
    {
        write_msgs_.pop_front();
        if (!write_msgs_.empty())
        {
            boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                boost::asio::buffer(write_msgs_.front().data(),
                    write_msgs_.front().length()),
                boost::bind(&chat_client::handle_write, this,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        do_close();
    }
}

void do_close()
{
    socket_.close();
}

private:

boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
tcp::socket socket_;
chat_message read_msg_;
};

struct timer {

timer(boost::asio::io_service& ios, const boost::posix_time::milliseconds&     t)
    :_t(t), _timer(ios, _t)
{
    _timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&timer::method, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void method(const boost::system::error_code& e) {
    std::cout << "ping" << std::endl;

        char line[20];
        for (int d = 0; d < 20; d++)
        {
            line[d] = 125;
        }
        using namespace std; // For strlen and memcpy.
        chat_message msg;
        msg.body_length(strlen(line));
        memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
        msg.encode_header();
        write_msgs_.push_front(msg);    
    if (e != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted) {
        _timer.expires_at(_timer.expires_at() + _t);
        _timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&timer::method, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
    }
}

private:
boost::posix_time::milliseconds _t;
boost::asio::deadline_timer _timer;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
void do_close();
try
{
    /*if (argc != 3)
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage: chat_client <host> <port>\n";
        return 1;
    }*/
    tcp::resolver::query query("127.0.0.1", "12345");
    tcp::resolver::iterator iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    chat_client c(io_service, iterator);

    boost::thread t(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io_service));

    char line[chat_message::max_body_length + 1];           
    timer timer(io_service, boost::posix_time::milliseconds(500));
    while (std::cin.getline(line, chat_message::max_body_length + 1))
    {
        using namespace std; // For strlen and memcpy.
        chat_message msg;
        msg.body_length(strlen(line));
        memcpy(msg.body(), line, msg.body_length());
        msg.encode_header();
        c.write(msg);
    }
    c.close();
    t.join();
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Измените код пожалуйста что бы заработал, или укажите где не верно. А может есть уже готовое решение?
Спасибо.